# localStorageDB not persisting data between javascript files

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have 2 javascript files.
1 of those files functions looks like this.

```
        var database = new localStorageDB("FormsDatabase", localStorage);
        this.Create = function (item) {
            database.insertOrUpdate("Value", { Id: item.Id }, item);
            database.commit();
        };
```

The other looks like this.

```
        var database = new localStorageDB("FormsDatabase", localStorage);
        this.SynchronizeValue = function () {
            var items = database.queryAll("Value", { query: function (row) { 
                 if (row.IsSent == false && row.IsDeleted == false) 
                 { return true; } else { return false; } }, limit: 100 });
        };
```

Why is it that the first file i can do a query right after doing an insertOrUpdate and a commit and i can get a return but in the second file the "Value" tables contents have dissapeared?

Comment: Are these files on the same domain?

Comment: Yes.  It's strange i guess it has something to do with the newing up of the database connection.  maybe the commit hasn't fully happened before the new database object gets newe'd up?

Comment: I thought you were using `localStorage` but you must be using a library I'm not familiar with.

Comment: It's a thin db layer over local storage called locaStorageDB. I've figured out that newing up a database variable creates for problems so only having 1 database object seems to alleviate what i'm experiencing here.